# Print file to printer or default printer through command prompt in windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a file located at `C:\printme.txt`

I want to print it to my printer which is named `POS80`

Is there not a simple command for windows in the command prompt to say `Print C:\printme.txt to POS80`?

It should be noted that POS80 is also the default printer so a command that does not include the printer name but just sends to the default printer would be acceptable too.

Answer (score 0):

Your mileage can vary using the legacy command `Print`

It MAY work if you have a line printer set to LPT1 and worth trying
`Print C:\printme.txt "POS80"` However I expect you are getting the error message "Unable to initialize device PRN" that is not unusual as PRN was traditionally LPT1.

Later you say its USB connected. which means its serial (old Com ports) whereas Line Printer (old LPT ports) were parallel hence the potential needs for fettling, but in windows you can use the port name for the printer and that resolves ports issue (files can become ports or vice versa) thus no real problem.

Now you could try messing with printer port redirections to get around that but it would likely mess up other application printing. Thus **by far the simplest is make the printer the default one which is what you have.**

> To avoid the Save Output File As dialog when adding a print job to the default queue, ensure that your default printer isn't Microsoft XPS Document Writer, Microsoft Print to PDF, or other print-to-file options.

So what is Windows 10 doing when you right click print? Generally it fires up the associated FTA (File Type Application) which for .txt (or similar chosen) is NotePad.

Thus the simplest way to command line print plain text is

```
NotePad /pt C:\printme.txt "POS80"
```

NotePad settings can be changed in the registry before and after you print, via the command line, even skewing letters (fun to prank colleagues if you use 1 degree off kilter), however you cannot set line spacing or add graphics, for those you need to step up to WordPad which will accept docx, rtf, odt and most simple text file types.

Several other file types can also be printed in a similar way such as graphics images, using mspaint.

Later you say you are sending html as text and want graphic output not textual.

So the x problem is the files are not plain.txt they are plain.htm so need translation from html by graphic conversion (rendering) to pass through a printer language converter (printer driver) That's a totally different question but the answer is still much the same.

Traditionally you would simply use

```
rundll32.exe mshtml.dll,PrintHTML "C:\printme.txt"
```

But security exploits have made that simplicity more of a challenge thus
best to run it like this.

`cd /D C:\Windows\System32 & rundll32.exe mshtml.dll,PrintHTML "C:\printme.txt"`
And Microsoft Current Policy is "User confirmation is needed to print an HTML page through MSHTML.DLL." **thus you need to hit print using sendkeys.**

If your preference is FireFox rendering, from the command line you needed to install an extension, however with tightened security in windows 10, I dont know if that's still possible.

If you wish to print xml or html graphically in windows 10+ you can ask Edge --headless to print those for you to PDF, either as screen shot or rendered text, **silently without enforced html confirmation !** And again you can print html automatically by using sendkeys to replace the user.

However printing PDF from the command line is where the real fun begins.

It is possible if the PDF is the correct type prepared for the printer (even a simple thermal or inkjet) then an old school `copy /b file.pdf "printer"` may work but dont send a big file to test, just a tiny `Hello World!`, or your carbon neutrality is instantly wiped out by reams of paper with one or two letters each.

My dirt cheap HP accepts files that can be viewed as PDF that start textually like this i.e. which have the PCLm 1 comment.

```
%PDF-1.7
%PCLm 1.0%
223 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/Resources <<
/XObject <<
/Image0 3 0 R
/Image1 4 0 R
```

For most POS printers a PDF either needs to be processed in middleware or usually top end firmware such as onboard Direct PDF

Thus we come back to using html bitmap and text directives that will either need a print driver or be programmed to a port or file for later `copy /b to device`.

As you no doubt know Microsoft have not made it simple to `print file.html default` in fact the opposite resulting in many third part apps for win xp-win 11 such as https://www.bersoft.com/htmlprint/index.htm#overview amongst many other options.

Comment: I should have mentioned that they will actually be HTML files and that they will be printed on a thermal printer which uses a USB Virtual Port and not LPT